# Can I remove a failed audit from my record if I pushed the wrong button accidentally?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

What is accident forgiveness? To me, it is the act of understanding that we are humans, and we make mistakes, so a person who makes a mistake should not be quickly judged or ridiculed. But rather, people should show that person empathy, compassion, and possibly humor.

I was reviewing some suggested edits on SO, and I came to a post that I didn't fully understand. I thought it should probably be rejected because the edit didn't make too much sense, but instead I was just going to skip over it. However, I was thinking about something else, and when I went to click "skip", I accidentally clicked "improve".

Right when it happened, time slowed down, and everything was slow motion. My brain automatically knew I made a mistake and I of course saw the "stop and pay attention" message yelling at me. I don't want this to be on my record forever. Is there anyway to get some accident forgiveness?

Comment: So you failed an audit. Big deal. It has no lasting repercussions. Move on.

Comment: You think you're overreacting? You know, just a bit.... This is like the climax, the most dramatic scene out of some movie...

Comment: **You're in good hands with Allstack**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You failed an audit. Go bury your head in sand, never to be seen again by the members of Stack Overflow. You are unworthy of being here.

No, but seriously, we've all failed audits, and not all of the fails have been accidents. The best of us have. If that's the only audit you've failed, **you're probably doing a good job**. Nobody really cares if someone fails one or two audits, but if it becomes a pattern, then it's really a problem, and the system will auto-ban you.

Also, just in case you didn't know, downvotes are different on meta. The downvotes for this question are (most likely) not because you failed an audit, but because people disagree with accident forgiveness, since it's unnecessary. The only way for "accident forgiveness", as you call it, is to keep reviewing, pass more audits, and this will probably be forgotten about.