# Accidental "Leave Open"

Tags: support, vote-to-close

The Close Review Queue is not pleasant. Jumped in as soon has hitting 3000. Failed two audits yesterday, and now I've managed to fat-mouse a `Leave Open` on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585091/complex-javascript-objects

In addition to taking a circuitous route in the future, is there anything I can do to take back the "Leave Open"?

I see I have 50 Close Votes. To use those on the Review Queue I estimate would take at least three hours. The idea of thousands of >3k zooming in and killing the queue in a short period of time is, I think, not a flyer.

Comment: Posting about it on meta is always a good way to attract extra voters to balance out your mistaken vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The close vote review queue is tougher than all the other queues you've been in before.

I thought it was really tough for the first 30-60 votes or so. But you get use to it, just like anything else.

The good thing about the close vote queue, is that you'll be able to max out your votes every day since there isn't a limited amount of questions to review. So because of this, is also another good thing, that you can click "skip", to get another question to review.

I wouldn't sit and review a single question for 10 minutes. After 30seconds to a minute you should have a pretty good idea to hit close/leave open/edit/skip for most questions.

Since you've already failed two audits, I'd recommend skipping the question if your not 99% sure. I believe that you'll get the hang of it though, very quickly.

And no you can not remove this failed audit from your record right now. It will automatically do so, according to the system. Don't ask when that is, because no one knows for sure.

I actually asked pretty much the same question a while back, take a look here [Can I remove a failed audit from my record if I pushed the wrong button accidentally?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213114/can-i-remove-a-failed-audit-from-my-record-if-i-pushed-the-wrong-button-accident)

Comment: Also remember that you can [filter the queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151994) to only specific tags and/or vote types.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thanks. My tags, turns out all the original flags came from me :-) I've filtered the types. Hopefully I'll get the hang of it.

Answer (score 4):

> is there anything I can do to take back the Leave Open

No, there is not.

Comment: Thanks. Feared so. I'll go and hide for a bit...

Comment: @BillWoodger part of the reason it takes multiple 'leave opens' (or close votes) to eject it form the queue is for that reason.  Be assured that other people [handled it](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3985956).  Clicking the wrong button (especially for someone new to the queue) isn't *that* uncommon (more often its from misunderstanding of the norms rather than a fat finger).

Comment: Does the system actually stop you from going to the question page and voting to close from there?

Comment: @Wooble No, but doing that wouldn't remove the "leave open" vote you've cast through the review queue, thus potentially kicking it out of the queue before it's been closed.